# Server side fix for widows in text string

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, razor

I'm having an issue with server side widows fix. 
I'm able to fix widows/orphans with client side javascript. 
However I would prefer to do it server side before the page renders. Unfortunately my C# is limited. How would I be able to accomplish this? Or at least get an idea of how to accomplish this.
Here's the javascript that I've used.

```
 var wordArray = $('element').text().split(' ');
 if (wordArray.length > 1) {
    wordArray[wordArray.length - 2] += '&nbsp;' + wordArray[wordArray.length 
   - 1];
   wordArray.pop();
   $(''element'').html(wordArray.join(' '));
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please read my comments inside the code

```
public string Model_fix(string ElementText)
{
    var result = string.Empty;
    // the compiler will set wordArray as List of string and not an array
    // list in c# is more similar to an array in javascript
    var wordArray = ElementText.ToString().Split(' ').ToList(); 
    if (wordArray.Count > 1)
    {
        wordArray[wordArray.Count - 2] += "'&nbsp;'" + wordArray[wordArray.Count - 1];
        wordArray.RemoveAt(wordArray.Count - 1); // equivilent to Array.pop in javascript
        result = string.Join(" ", wordArray); // equivilent to Array.join() in javascript
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Jonathana, this was a big help in understanding. Cheers

Comment: glad i could help, if you find it useful, you please mark it as an answer. cheers (-: